# AJAX - How to update a specific div with ajax in Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to update a certain `Div` field with `.html`  file with the help of AJAX. And I don't want to use `iframe` tag.

I have searched lot but I cant get any answers. Could You please suggest me some examples for this scenario in Spring MVC. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: make an ajax call to the controller's method which returns a view which would be your _jsp/html_ file then use `.html()` to place the returned view to the document.

Comment: could you please give me some example  in this...

Comment: have a look at the [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/)-function

Comment: @SiVi do you have your method which returns the view?

Comment: @Jai yes of-course.. which means i have to use `@responsebody` for ajax call where return type is modelandview... is that correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
$('#mainNav a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.getAttribut('href');
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(response) {
        $('.contentPlaceholder').html(response);
      },
      error: function(res) {
        alert("error");
      }
    });
});
```

Where i am guessing that you have a main navigation `$('#mainNav a')` to your views like :

```
<ul id='mainNav'>
    <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">about</a></li>
</ul>
```